# "will" for future plans (+ specific time involved - day, date, hour)

Tags: future, will-be-going, will-future

Can I use "will" instead of "going to or present continuous" when asking or making statements about someone's plans with a specific time involved?

for example:

1. *I will meet her Monday morning at 7 am.*
   (we have an arrangement)
2. *What time will you meet her?*
   (tell me your plans)
3. *She will arrive at 9am. tomorrow.*
   (she has an arrangement with my brother)
4. *What time will she come home?*
   (tell me her plans)

Comment: Going to + infinitive is the expression of present continuous.  That is a future tense expression.   Could you please clarify your question?  Do you mean using "going to + infinitive" can be used instead of "will" or vice-versa?

Comment: Yes. Vice versa. "I will meet her Monday morning at 7 am" instead of "I am going to meet her Monday morning at 7 am"

Comment: _Will_ may be used in all of those sentence. So may _be going to_. There are very few differences between them, and these rarely determine which one to use. It's more often a matter of how many syllables one wants to use.

Comment: The semantics and pragmatics of **will** versus **be going to** are sometimes alike and sometimes very different. They are not always interchangeable. Here is a full Monty on this, if you want to read  through it: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/248670122_A_relevance-theoretic_account_of_be_going_to In everyday speech, I would not use them the same way. I hesitate to give an answer because it would take me too long to figure it out formally.

Answer (score 0):

You can say both going to and will for all of these sentences.  They have subtle differences as to what they are emphasizing about future time.

> I will meet her Monday morning at 7 AM.
>
> I am going to meet her Monday morning at 7 AM.

The first one implies a prediction while the latter implies an intent or a plan to do that in the future.

This link does a good job of describing [the differences in meaning between "Going to + infinitive" vs. will](https://www.grammar.cl/Notes/Future_Will_vs_Going.htm)